# At a loss with JSON, PHP, AS3: Cannot trace correct value

Tags: php, mysql, json, actionscript-3

I have used JSON objects before and they work perfectly but the JSON objects that I made before have been from a result of fetched MySQL entries. Now, I am trying to make my own JSON object through an array in PHP and it shows correctly in the database but I cannot access any of the values like before.

```
$chatArray = array(
 array(
     'chatusername' => 'Troy',
     'chatuserid' => '123',
     'chatmessage' => 'Hello World'
 ),

 array(
     'chatusername' => 'Nick',
     'chatuserid' => '124',
     'chatmessage' => 'Testing'
 ));
```

$inputArray = json_encode($chatArray);

That is what I input into my database and like I said it works good. Then I call for it in a separate .php and get this

```
{"chat":"[{\"chatuserid\": \"123\", \"chatmessage\": \"Hello World\", \"chatusername\": \"Troy\"}, {\"chatuserid\": \"124\", \"chatmessage\": \"Testing\", \"chatusername\": \"Nick\"}]"}
```

It throws the "chat" out front which is the column name in my database which I am not sure why.

When I trace it I can only seem to trace it by

```
var messageArray:Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);
trace(messageArray.chat);
```

Any time I try to reference say messageArray.chat.chatusername it returns an error.

I'm sorry I know it is probably a simple solution but I have been searching and working at it for a few hours now.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I *think* you need `messageArray.chat[0].chatusername` for the first message, and `messageArray.chat[1].chatusername` for the second message. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's what I thought but then it returns an error  ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value.

Comment: Ah, I see. The JSON output is not correct. The contents of `messageArray.chat` is actually a JSON-encoded string itself. You'll need to `JSON.parse` that separately, or fix the PHP file that generates that output.

Comment: Ok that makes sense and I figured that may have been a problem until I printed $result before encoding and it threw back an array.

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT chat FROM markerinfo WHERE markerid='$chatid'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
`

that's the .php that returns the JSON value from the database, am I doing something wrong there? If I don't encode it in the php then in as3 I get an error saying invalid parse input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the PHP code that generates your JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866962/at-a-loss-with-json-php-as3-cannot-trace-correct-value/46867238#comment80681619_46866962):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT chat FROM markerinfo WHERE markerid='$chatid'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Keep in mind that the `chat` column in your database contains a JSON-string.

This code is not decoding the JSON-string in your database, so `$result` will be an array containing a JSON-string as well:

```
$result = [
    'chat' => '[{"chatusername":"Troy","chatuserid":"123","chatmessage":"Hello World"},{"chatusername":"Nick","chatuserid":"124","chatmessage":"Testing"}]'
];
```

By passing that array through `json_encode()`, you're **double-encoding** your JSON-string.

For your purposes, you can probably get away with:

```
echo $result['chat'];
```

But, if you want the `chat` column name to be included in your output, you will have to decode the stored JSON first:

```
$result['chat'] = json_decode($result['chat']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Ahhh brilliant `echo $result['chat'];`did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is related to the php side when it encodes your array, it will escape it with slashes, and this confuses the JSON parsing in your JS side. Try to add the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option to your `json_encode` function like this:

```
$inputArray = json_encode($chatArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Check the `json_encode` function documentation for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @TroyMyers did you try printing the result of `$inputArray`? You should check from where is that backslashes escaping is coming. If not the `json_encode` then it could be your mysql query escaping the content itself. Could you please share the insert code with us?